# AngularJS disable ng-click when a variable equals

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<span class="column__list--total fa" ng-class="{'fa-check': skill.done == 1, 'fa-times red': skill.done == 0}" ng-click="skill.disabled || toggleSkill(skill.id, person.id)" ng-hide="$root.user[0].auth == 2"></span>

<span class="column__list--total fa" ng-class="{'fa-check': skill.done == 1, 'fa-times red': skill.done == 0}" ng-show="$root.user[0].auth == 2"></span>
```

At the moment I am using the above, they are equally the same but one will be hidden using `ng-hide` when a variable equals `2`

The reason being I want to disable `ng-click` on the element.

Do I need to keep it as two separate elements or is it possible to disable `ng-click` when `$root.user[0].auth == 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a condition in your `ng-click`, why not add another?

`ng-click="$root.user[0].auth == 2 || skill.disabled || toggleSkill(skill.id, person.id)"`

Answer (score 0):

You can just do `return;` in your `toggleSkill()` before executing any other code.

```
$scope.toggleSkill = function(skill.id, person.id) {
    if ($root.user[0].auth == 2) {
        return;
    }

    // Rest of your code
}
```